# seq to force evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

To run in constant space, `mean2` uses `sumlen2` which `seq`s summation and count. But again my belief and textbook, `mean2` still runs with space leak. What's the mistake?

Any helps will be appreciated deeply.

```
-- Thinking Functionally with Haskell by R. Bird
-- Chapter 7.2 Controlling space

sumlen1 = foldl' g (0,0)
  where g (s,n) x = (s+x,n+1)

sumlen2 = foldl' g (0,0)
  where g (s,n) x = s `seq` n `seq` (s+x,n+1)

-- has space leak
mean1 [] = 0
mean1 xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where (s,n) = sumlen1 xs        

-- should run in constant space    
mean2 [] = 0
mean2 xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where (s,n) = sumlen2 xs        

λ> mean1 [1..1000000]
500000.5
(1.99 secs, 520,962,648 bytes)
λ> mean2 [1..1000000]
500000.5
(1.36 secs, 516,288,128 bytes)
```

Comment: Can't see the issue, but is that "bytes" the total bytes allocated or the peak allocation. Perhaps it's the former, in which case `sumlen2` is running in constant space.

Comment: Thank you. I've regarded `bytes` as peak allocation, However it's the total bytes allocated. `sumlen2` runs with constant space

Comment: For performance measurements be sure to compile your code with `ghc -O2`. The GHCi interpreter does not optimize as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Clinton commented out, the performance metrics from ghci is the total bytes allocation. `sumlen2` runs with constant space.